# How to fix this error Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. not want to add ""fielddata": true"

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

My Elastic MApping

```
creator: {
  normalizer: 'customNormalizer',
  type: 'keyword',
  index: true,
  fields: {
    raw: {
      type: 'keyword',
    },
  },
};
```

Field data can not be added. Field data can consume a lot of heap space, especially when loading high cardinality text fields.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

`type: 'keyword'` does not need to have `"fielddata": true`. This option is only applicable to `text` fields.